# No desktop appears after logging in using XDMCP

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, xdmcp

I just installed a test machine with Ubuntu LTS 14.04 and I went to configure the XDMCP access and found that the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` is not there anymore.

In Google I found that now it is in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf` and there I modified the settings to enable XDMCP and some others:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-show-manual-login=true

[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true

[SeatDefaults]
xserver-allow-tcp=true
```

But when I try to log in using Xming from a windows machine, I can enter the username and password but afterwards no desktop appears, only the background from the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

I created this file `/etc/lightm/lightdm.conf`:

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-allow-tcp=true
xserver-share=true
xdmcp-port=177
greeter-show-remote-login=true

[XDMCPServer]
enabled=true
port=177
```

Then I installed `gnome-session-flashback` because Unity doesn't work in the XDMCP client.

Comment: I did the same in a new installation but I am still getting the same window with the background and no desktop. http://postimg.org/image/3zwog18jd/