# How do I set-up LightDM and gnome-session-flashback to use XDMCP?

Tags: networking, gnome, lightdm, xdmcp

I'm trying to create a terminal session on another computer in my local area network.

I have used XDMCP in the past, but it's pretty long ago ('06 & '07). I remember it being a breeze to set-up and kinda worked in Ubuntu out of the box. Now it seems things aren't as easy any more.

I have followed what is described [in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452802/no-desktop-appears-after-loged-in-using-xdmcp). But I am not actually getting to the login screen using the XDMCP connection. No error message when I attempt to connect though. I can ping the local machine I wish to connect to.

Any advise or guides to making XDMCP working?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I am using a windows xdmcp client (MobaXterm), however, its pretty straightforward with the following provisos 
1 - use lightdm as the window manager on ubuntu server
2 - I could not get unify desktop to work, use metacity
3 - that thread worked for me, as long as you do 1 and 2 above